# How to uninstall Typesafe Activator?

Tags: typesafe-activator

I've managed to install and totally screwed up my installation of [Typesafe Activator](https://typesafe.com/activator).

Is there a way to uninstall the tool so I can get back to a clean slate and start over?

I'm on Window 8.1 with JDK 1.8.0_25.

Comment: How did you install activator? How much got it screwed up? What are the issues?

Comment: running `activator new play-scala play-scala` creates the folders correctly running `activator ui` appears to start correctly but localhost:8888 doesnt response. No errors are logged it just seems to `activator run` stops and doesnt finish. I also some times get a MimeType error message which I cant seem to get at the moment.

Comment: Did you solve it? I'm not on Win8, isn't there an equivalent of the applications panel for it? On 7 you can usually uninstall it as any other program, if I remember correctly...

Comment: I was deluding myself... even on Win7 there's no uninstaller

Answer (score 3):

I just installed activator a few days ago and I also ran into a problem with it (an unresolved dependency for *oauth.signpost* when I tried to run *activator ui*. In the end I managed to get *activator ui* working by deleting *~/.activator* *~/.sbt* and *~/.ivy2* folders and reinstalling activator. There really needs to be an uninstall feature in my opinion. I hope I haven't inadvertently broken something else by deleting those folders.

Answer (score 1):

Try to locate your .activator folder and delete this. 
It's usual in C:\Users\<"user">\.activator