# Uninstall typesafe activator from command line OSX El Capitan

Tags: macos, playframework, terminal, typesafe-activator

I have seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26884898/how-to-uninstall-typesafe-activator) but it didn't work for me.

I want to cleanly uninstall and reinstall typesafe activator.  I deleted the `.activator`, `.ivy2` and `.sbt` directories from my machine.  I also searched (with Finder) for all `activator` unix executables and deleted all of them.    However, when I run the `activator` command it starts downloading dependencies e.g:

```
Detected MAC OSX launched script....
Swapping to UI
Getting com.typesafe.activator activator-launcher 1.3.10 ...
```

What should I do to *completely* remove activator from my machine?

Comment: Any chances you installed it over brew ?

Comment: ^^ OK so I ran `brew uninstall typesafe-activator` and it worked.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Ran `brew uninstall --force typesafe-activator` and my machine is clean.